# How to get Propery value in the javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a property named `Month` that having the value "March"
I am using the following JavaScript code on my page to access the value of property.
but the following line code giving error `March` is undefined.

```
var MM=<%=Month%>;
```

What is wrong here? What is the correct code to access the property value in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

If you display the source in browser, you'll see this:

```
var MM=March;
```

This is incorrect because March would have to be another variable or so. If you want to assign the string "March" into the variable, use this:

```
var MM="<%=Month%>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
var MM=<%=Month%>;
```

doesn't establish a magic link between the javascript variable `MM` and the ASP.Net property `Month`. Rather it will generate a text at the server side that will only be interpreted as javascript when it arrives at the browser.

The ASP.Net page doesn't know that the value will end up in javascript. Neither does javascript know about asp.net properties.

So check the text that is generated by asp.net (do a 'view source' in the browser) to make sure it's valid javascript. And if not, adjust your server-side code.